# How to force first detail band to print on top of the page when there are two bands in Detail section?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using 2 detail bands to display a table in a report and I am using a variable which reset at page count as print when the expression of first detail band: `($V{detail_header}.equals(new java.lang.Integer(1)))`

For example

[image]

At the same time, I am using split type as prevent for the second detail band.

But sometimes I get a weird behaviour as below

[image]

This line contained bold letters ---> **detail band 1**
Remaining ---> **detail band 2**

I want this detail band 1 to print on the top of the page all the time. Is this possible?